# Right-adjoint functors commute with limits

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, adjoint-functors

In page 493 of Paolo Aluffi's *Algebra: Chapter 0*, it says (Lemma 1.17):

> If $\mathcal G: D \to C$ has a left-adjoint $\mathcal F: C\to D$ and $\mathcal A: I\to D$ is another functor, then there is a canonical isomorphism $$\mathcal G(\lim \limits_{\gets} \mathcal A) \simeq \lim \limits_{\gets}(\mathcal G \circ \mathcal A)$$ (**if the limits exist**).

I have two questions on this lemma:

- In Aluffi's book, it seems to be one of the conditions that both $\lim \limits_{\gets} \mathcal A$ and $\lim \limits_{\gets}(\mathcal G \circ \mathcal A)$ exist. I wonder whether the existence of one of the limits implies the existence of the other limit.
- I believe by 'canonical', it means the isomorphism is somewhat a natural transformation. However, I can't figure out how exactly it can be seen as a natural transformation.

Comment: How can there be an isomorphism if one of the limits doesn't exist? There is nothing for it to be an isomorphism between then. Or do you mean that one of them existing should imply that the other exists?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, I mean one of them existing should imply the other exists. I have edited the question.